# Doit-on dire « Quelle confiture est la meilleure ? » ou « Quelle confiture est-elle la meilleure ? »?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions, sujet, pronom-de-reprise

Dans le cas « La confiture est-elle bonne ? », je n'ai aucun doute (même si on pourrait arguer que « La confiture est bonne ? », bien qu'incorrect, est utilisé dans un registre familier).

Par contre, doit-on dire « Quelle confiture est la meilleure ? » ou « Quelle confiture est-elle la meilleure ? »

Spontanément, je dirais que la première tournure est la bonne, et que *quelle confiture* étant le sujet, il n'a pas besoin d'être répété, mais d'un autre côté la deuxième ne me paraît pas incorrecte pour autant. À vrai dire, voir les deux côte-à-côte me laisse davantage perplexe et je ne parviens pas à me décider.

Qu'en est-il ?

---

English summary: the standard formal way of asking a yes-no question in French is e.g. “*La confiture est-elle bonne ?*” (“Is the jam good?”). But what about the case when the topic of the question is an aspect of the subject — “Quelle confiture est(-elle) la meilleure ?” (“Which jam is the best?”)? I can't decide which one is correct.

Comment: Je ne dirais jamais "quelle confiture est-elle la meilleure ?" Mais je dirais "quel jour vous convient-il le plus ?" Etonnant. (En fait plus j'y pense-t-il, et moins je sais.)

Comment: @Subtenante j'ai le même problème — plus je regarde une des deux formes et plus j'ai l'impression que l'autre est correcte. Ou pas.

Comment: Moi j'en suis sûr (ça fait 3 secondes que j'ai lu la question) : j'aurais jamais dit la seconde. Je réponds vite parce qu'après je ne vais plus savoir.

Comment: @subtenante:  je pense que c'est à rapprocher de "quel jour vous convient-t-y ?", ou "quel jour vous convient-tu ?"  Ce n'est donc pas le pronom "il", mais un moyen d'appuyer la question qui a disparu du français moderne de France, mais encore répandu des ses campagnes et au Québec.

Comment: Autres exemples: _Qui veut de la confiture ?_ vs. _Qui veut-il de la confiture ?_ ou encore _Quelqu'un pourrait élaborer un peu ?_ vs. _Quelqu'un pourrait-il élaborer un peu ?_ ou encore _Quelqu'un aurait-il l'amabilité de répondre en citant les références nécessaires ?_

Comment: N'est-il pas plus "naturel" de dire *Quelle est la meileure confiture ?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ce *elle* est un pronom de reprise. Il est obligatoire dans l'interrogation globale (*La confiture de maman est-elle la meilleure ?*) mais on a ici une interrogation partielle qui porte sur le sujet; dans ce cas la reprise est un usage minoritaire mais constant et ancien (Grevisse donne une page d'exemples et je ne résiste pas à l'envie de citer celui-ci : *Combien de grammaires donnent-elles le mot de l'énigme ?*)

Pour les exemple supplémentaires.

> Qui veut de la confiture ? vs. Qui veut-il de la confiture ?

Même chose que pour la qualité de la confiture, interrogation partielle commençant avec un pronom interrogatif sujet, la reprise est minoritaire.

> Quelqu'un pourrait élaborer un peu ?

C'est une phrase interrogative et le fait qu'elle soit interrogative n'est audible que par l'intonation.

> Quelqu'un pourrait-il élaborer un peu ?
>   Quelqu'un aurait-il l'amabilité de répondre en citant les références nécessaires ?

Interrogations totales avec un sujet « complexe », c'est la forme normale.

Référence: *le bon Usage*, Grevisse, 12 édition refondue par André Goosse, Duculot, Paris - Louvain-la-Neuve, 1986, pp. 643 et seq.

---

English summary: the word *elle* is a *pronom de reprise*. It is mandatory when the question is global (“*La confiture de maman est-elle la meilleure ?*” — “Is mum's jam the best?”). But in this case the question is partial, targeting the subject only. In this case, the *pronom de reprise* is a well-established, but minority usage.

Comment: Pour le premier, pas moyen de faire sans sauf à utiliser _est-ce que_. Pour le second, ça dépend un peu du ton. Même si ce n'est pas relevé par Grevisse, tous ses exemples sont des phrases interrogatives qui tiennent de l'exclamative. Si je les pense comme des questions rhétoriques, ça passe, si je les prends telles quelles, ça passe mal.  L'exemple initial et celui de subtenante passent mal pour moi, peut-être parce qu'ils ne sont pas propice à l'emphase.

Comment: Ca me fait penser à une autre question plutôt intéressante : faut-il écrire « ce *elle* » ou bien « cet *elle* » ? Si c'est « ce *elle* », comment on le prononce ? Avec un coup de glotte ou pas ?

Comment: @Brennan, je fais la liaison dans _est-ce elle qui t'a donné ce devoir ?_ (oui, c'est la rentrée des classes cette semaine).

Answer (score 6):

La réponse d'un francophone est bonne, elle a le mérite d'évoquer la mécanique des pronoms de reprise, mais au sujet de l'usage et des idiomes, j'ajouterais simplement que les deux formules proposées me semblent inusitées, au profit du plus courant :

> Quelle est la meilleure confiture ?

voire

> Quelle est la meilleure des confitures ?