# Quand doit-on reprendre le sujet par un pronom personnel ? (inversion)

Tags: grammaire, questions, sujet

Par exemple, on peut dire : « Comment va votre mère ? », ou bien « Comment votre mère va-t-elle ? ». Mais est-ce qu'il y a une règle de grammaire qui gouverne quand on peut et quand on doit reprendre le sujet ?

Comment: Question similaire: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/993/79

Answer (score 2):

À mon sens c'est une distinction entre le français parlé et le français écrit.

À l'écrit, la formulation correcte est :

> Comment votre mère va-t-elle ?

À l'oral, on dira plutôt :

> Comment va votre mère ?

Comment: Y a-t-il une raison pour le vote négatif ?

Answer (score 1):

Je réponds à l'intuition parce que dans ma connaissance de la grammaire, une question présente usuellement la structure inversée du premier exemple.

- Le deuxième exemple est plutôt *lourd*,
- Par contre, il crée une emphase assez évidente sur le sujet (même si cela semble inutile à bien y regarder)

Je ne vois pas quand cette formulation DEVRAIT être employée. A mon sens, elle n'est pas assez  correcte pour l'être et me rappelle des tournures employées dans le théâtre classique (Molière par exemple). Du vieilli donc. Ou peut-être, cela a à voir avec un niveau de langue soutenu...

Answer (score -1):

just the way it sounds to me (Neapolitan, Italian, Spanish, no French)...

your second example does not sound French.
I would expect: "votre mère, Comment va-t-elle?".
hope it is self explanatory, you need a subject in the sentence.
"votre mère" in this case is outside of the sentence.

Comment: My native speaker's inner grammar tells me that it does sound French.