# « Combien de Français sont-ils concernés par » est-il correct ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions, sujet, pronom-de-reprise

Je viens d'entendre sur France Info cette construction :

> Combien de Français sont-ils concernés par cette réforme ?

L'utilisation du *ils* ne me semble pas aller avec une question commençant par *combien*. Est-ce correct grammaticalement ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doit-on dire « Quelle confiture est la meilleure ? » ou « Quelle confiture est-elle la meilleure ? »?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/993/doit-on-dire-quelle-confiture-est-la-meilleure-ou-quelle-confiture-est-e)

Comment: @Joubarc, j'ai hésité. C'est la même structure, une fois après _quel_, une fois après _combien de_.

Comment: Oui, j'ai vu après que tu y avais fait référence dans ta réponse. J'ai aussi hésité, note bien, mais il me semble aussi que c'est la même structure.

Answer (score 12):

Le journaliste a vraisemblablement fait une confusion entre ces deux structures possibles :

> Combien de Français sont concernés par cette réforme ?

et

> Les Français sont-ils concernés par cette réforme ?

---

Une autre possibilité correcte aurait été :

> Combien y a-t-il de Français concernés par cette réforme ?

Answer (score 6):

Le pronom de reprise avec un sujet introduit par *combien de* est une tendance assez forte, ancienne quoique minoritaire, en particulier dans les phrases négatives d'après Grevisse, *le bon usage*, douzième édition qui, pour les phrases positives, donne des exemples tirés entre autres de Mauriac, Vercors, Vaugelas et Molière.

Edit : [On a déjà traité](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/993/176) du pronom de reprise après *quel*, et j'avais cité alors *combien de grammaires donnent-elles le mot de l'énigme ?*

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'une tendance forte et minoritaire ? N'est-ce pas contradictoire ? (J'avoue avoir un peu de mal avec la structure grammaticale même de la réponse)

Comment: Minoritaire: il y a moins de personnes qui utilisent ce tour que de personnes qui ne l'utilisent pas. Forte, ceux qui utilisent ce tour sont suffisemment nombreux et influents pour qu'il ne soit pas anecdotique.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis d'accord avec toi, le "ils" me semble de trop dans cette phrase.