# « Comment devient » ou « comment devient-il » ?

Tags: pronoms, questions, interrogative, pronom-de-reprise

Que doit-on dire :

> Comment un lieu devient agréable ?
>
> Comment un lieu devient-il agréable ?

Les deux sont-ils corrects, ou incorrects, ou ne signifient(-ils ?) pas la même chose, etc. ?

Comment: ne ressemble-t-elle pas fortement à cette [question là](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/993/doit-on-dire-quelle-confiture-est-la-meilleure-ou-quelle-confiture-est-e) ?

Comment: @CédricJulien, la différence est que dans ta référence l'interrogation partielle porte sur le sujet, dans cette question, elle porte sur autre chose. Là le pronom de reprise était d'un emploi minoritaire, dans ce cas-ci, il est majoritaire au point qu'on doute pour le moment de la validité de son absence.

Comment: @CédricJulien je ne savais pas que ça marchait aussi avec la confiture :-) Je découvre ces notions d'interrogation partielle et globale, et j'ai un peu de mal à comprendre, mais ça devrait venir-t-il pas ?

Comment: @Istao, interrogation totale -> porte sur la totalité de la phrase; on répond par _oui_, _si_ ou _non_. Interrogation partielle, porte sur une partie de la phrase en cherchant un complément d'information, on répond en donnant la partie qui manque. (_mais ça devrait venir-t-il pas ?_ est incorrect; je suppose que tu voulais dire _mais ça devrait venir, n'est-ce pas ?_).

Comment: @Unfrancophone merci ; moi j'appelle ça une question fermée (votre totale) ou ouverte (votre partielle).

Comment: @Istao, pour moi la nomenclature totale/partielle est grammaticale, tandis que fermée/ouverte est sémantique.  Si une interrogation totale est toujours une question fermée, une interrogation partielle peut l'être aussi (_Est-ce Pierre ou Paul qui est venu ?_ est une interrogation partielle mais une question fermée)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normalement, dans une phrase interrogative il y a inversion du sujet.

> Comment devient-il agréable ?

Quand le sujet est complexe, on devrait avoir

> *Comment devient un lieu agréable ?

qui ne se dit pas.  On laisse le sujet en place, et on utilise un pronom de reprise :

> Comment un lieu devient-il agréable ?

L'absence du pronom de reprise n'est pas envisagée par Grevisse (ou du moins, je n'ai pas trouvé où), ce qui semble confirmer l'impression qu'elle est incorrecte.

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que la deuxième formulation *devient-il* est la seule grammaticalement correcte. Du moins c'est celle que j'emploierais à l'écrit, même dans un mail plutôt informel.

La première est compréhensible et éventuellement utilisée à l'orale, même si j'aurais tendance à accentuer la question en disant par exemple : *Tu sais comment un lieu devient agréable ?*

Comment: Merci, c'est un peu ce que j'ai tendance à penser aussi, mais pourquoi la deuxième est-elle grammaticalement correcte et pas du tout la première ?

Answer (score 2):

Mon correcteur [Antidote 8](http://www.druide.com/antidote.html) indique que la première phrase est fautive et requiert l'inversion:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Il y a une subtilité d'usage, s'il s'agit de donner une impression d'interrogation pour attirer l'attention sur la solution que l'on va proposer :

> Comment un lieu devient agréable? : en appliquant la bonne solution
>   ....

Sinon, le pronom est nécessaire, surtout si le locuteur/scripteur espère une réponse : il  lèvera alors toute ambiguïté sur son attente.

A l'oral, l'intonation peut se substituer au pronom, et il peut être parfois omit sans gêner le dialogue.

Comment: Oui je suis assez d'accord avec ça, et j'ai même tendance à dire que dans ce cas le _-il_ serait fautif : le raisonnement coule beaucoup mieux sans lui. Mais il s'agit encore et toujours seulement d'impression. Peut être existe-il une troisième forme de question, en plus des globales et partielles ?