# Dans quels pays les coureurs se rendent ils?

Tags: grammaire

I'm reading "Assimil New French with Ease", and in lesson 90 it goes:

> Quand le Tour de France a-t-il été créé?
>
> Combien y avait-il d'étapes à l'origine?
>
> Combien y en a-t-il aujourd'hui?
>
> **Dans quels pays les coureurs se rendent-ils ?**

Now I don't understand, why we need an "ils" in the last line? The question means

> To (in) which countries do the racers go?

*To which countries* is the *Dans quels pays*, why there is still an *ils* at the end of the line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Pourquoi l'hôtel est-il complet?" Why est-il and not just est?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24563/pourquoi-lh%c3%b4tel-est-il-complet-why-est-il-and-not-just-est)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask a question, you need to inverse the subject ("ils") and the verb ("rendent").

In this sentence, the verb is "rendre":

> Dans quels pays les coureurs se **rendent**-ils ?

Another example:

> Je vais à Paris. (I'm going to Paris)
>
> Vais-je à Paris ? (Am I going to Paris ?)

Another tip: In some cases, you will have to add a "t" between the subject and the verb, except if your verb already finish by a "t", or a "d":

> aime-t-il ?
>
> parle-t-elle ?
>
> Sai**t**-il ?
>
> Pren**d**-on ?

More info: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/euphonic-inversion/

Comment: but... isn't *les coureurs* the subject already?

Comment: Yes, indeed: "Les coureurs" is the subject, but it is also a noun: You need to add after the verb the pronoun, which is here "ils", only if it is a noun

Comment: Cette réponse est au mieux incomplète et sans ce commentaire ne répond pas à la question qui porte sur le "ils". J’aimerais voir un contre-exemple où le sujet n’est pas un nom dans lequel on ne fait donc pas cet ajout de pronom. J’avoue avoir du mal à en trouver...

Comment: @LaurentS. : https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/la-phrase/la-phrase-interrogative

Comment: @athos: There is also a topic which could also be related to your question: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/993/doit-on-dire-quelle-confiture-est-la-meilleure-ou-quelle-confiture-est-e